# Getting code from the Wolfram Demonstrations Projects

Tags: code-request, demonstrations

I saw from mathematica's website, there is a fantastic project about the 2D Riemann Sum.

[Riemann Sums For Functions of Two Variables](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RiemannSumsForFunctionsOfTwoVariables/)

I want to see the similar effect in my *Mathematica* (with different function), and there is no code provided. How do I reproduce the same using *Mathmatica*?

Comment: [Code provided](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/sourcecode.html?demoname=RiemannSumsForFunctionsOfTwoVariables&demodisplayname=Riemann%20Sums%20for%20Functions%20of%20Two%20Variables)

Comment: @Artes, how do you get the source code? I download '.nb', but it is exactly the same as the webpage.

Answer (score 5):

For all of the Wolfram Demonstrations Projects, you can download a notebook file containing all the code used to create the demonstration.

To do so, go to the [demonstration page](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RiemannSumsForFunctionsOfTwoVariables/) and look along the right hand side of the page for a link that says **Download Author Code** (it's right below the big, orange Download Demonstration button). Note that the "preview" option alone does not give everything needed to recreate the demonstration. If for some reason your browser isn't loading this section of the page properly, you can download the code for this particular demonstration [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/downloadauthornb.cgi?name=RiemannSumsForFunctionsOfTwoVariables).

The downloaded notebook can be opened to view and modify the Mathematica code necessary to recreate the demonstration. By default the notebook will have much of the code sections hidden, but these can be viewed by expanding the relevant cells in the notebook. Fortunately, these sections tend to be very well documented.

Comment: I download the code, but it looks like the same as the webpage.How did you find the source code?

Comment: In the notebook, look at the section called **Initialization Code**. In Mathematica's notebook front-end, you can right click on the blue brackets on the right and select **Open/Close Group**. This should reveal the extra code that isn't available in the preview. You can do the same for the **Manipulate** section to see the code listed in the preview. I'm using Mathematica 9, but I don't think the procedure will be very different for other versions.